# App Services EasyAuth for protecting API with OIDC

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, openid-connect, easy-auth

I currently have a solution where I have an OIDC provider, a client that obtained a token from that provider, and a protected resource (API).

Currently I'm using Easy Auth on the API, so far it seems to validate the token correctly. The only problem is the API needs a secret (not optional).

In my experience, the API should be able to check the signature, audience and expiration etc without needing a client_id and client_password itself. It seems to me that Easy Auth assumes that everything is a client.

Is there a way to secure an API with Easy Auth OIDC, where the API does not require a secret but will just validate the token knowing the IDP? (Or do I *need* to use another Azure product such as API Management)

[image]

**Edit**: I think I just learned that in this situation I can add any bogus value to secret and it is not used. The Client ID is used as Audience for validation by Easy Auth.

- `Client ID` is used as `Audience` for token validation by Easy Auth.
- `Client secret` is ignored completely by Easy Auth. Can be any value.

Comment: How did you figure out that client ID is used for the audience?

Comment: I think it was visible in the error message that Audience validation failed. It would've obscured the Audience value, but with some experimenting I found out the correct value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are following standard behaviour of validating JWTs in the API, rather than using OpenID Connect - so all good. OIDC is mostly a client concern which led to some confusion on my part, and hence my original answer. I thought I'd add a couple of follow on points below, since they may be useful to you in future when working with Azure AD.

**DISTINCT ACCESS TOKENS PER API**

APIs registered in Azure AD APIs follow the rationale behind the [Resource Indicators](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8707) draft spec. Each access token can only be used by a single API. Therefore each API requires a Client ID to be registered, that is written to access tokens issued for that API.

**OAUTH STANDARDS AND MULTIPLE APIs**

When there are multiple APIs, the most standard OAuth 2.0 architecture in a same company setup is for a set of related APIs to forward access tokens to each other. Each API then validates the access token, which is a fast operation. This is very much recommended, and is sometimes called a [zero trust architecture](https://curity.io/resources/learn/zero-trust-overview/). In a microservices architecture this also allows user context to be maintained securely.

For this to work, a set of related APIs should be able to all declare the same audience, such as `api.mycompany.com`. Meanwhile each API will have different scopes, to ensure that if an API outside the remit of the original client is called, the request is immediately rejected. See [scope best practices](https://curity.io/resources/learn/scope-best-practices/) for a real world example.

**AZURE AD AND MULTIPLE APIs**

For multiple APIs to call each other with Azure AD access tokens, token exchange must be used. This involves each API acting as a client, in which case the client secret you have registered will be used. An example request where the API acts as a client is shown below, from a Node.js sample of mine. Note that the API acting as a client sends its original token as a [User Assertion](https://curity.io/resources/learn/jwt-assertion/#user-authentication-using-jwts):

```js
const formData = new URLSearchParams();
formData.append('grant_type', 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer');
formData.append('client_id', this._configuration.graphClient.clientId);
formData.append('client_secret', this._configuration.graphClient.clientSecret);
formData.append('assertion', accessToken);
formData.append('scope', this._configuration.graphClient.scope);
formData.append('requested_token_use', 'on_behalf_of');

const options = {
    url: this._configuration.tokenEndpoint,
    method: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'accept': 'application/json',
    },
    httpsAgent: this._httpProxy.agent,
};

const response = await axios.request(options as AxiosRequestConfig) as any;
return response.data.access_token!;
```

Comment: Hi Gary. Thanks for the quick reply. I know how to do JWT validations in our .NET apps. My client has chosen to use Easy Auth as an extra layer (updated & maintained by MS). Fine grained authorization will be done in the app with the pre-validated token. I Was just wondering why everything needs a secret, and if that can be circumvented. As I stand now it looks like even though the secret is mandatory, it is not used for mere API protection.

Comment: No problem - confusion on my part, since I thought you were using OIDC in APIs. I added a couple of points of interest above - since the client secret is also needed sometimes.

Comment: Hi thanks the post had some eye openers on audience and scopes. Yes calling it OIDC was a bit confusing since it was not related to those flows exactly in my context. I was mainly concerned with the OAuth part. OIDC is what my provider (IdentityServer4) is called when selecting Easy Auth. Its either a preconfigured provider (such as FB or Google) or OIDC. I understand that _some_ API's are clients, but my problem is the Easy Auth considers _every_ app it is enabled for as a client (since you HAVE to provide `Client ID` and `Client Secret`).

Comment: By the way Gary for clarification, when talking about forwarding access tokens do you mean that the API's request their own access tokens and forward those? Or do you mean that API1 receives an initial access token that it forwards to API2 which forwards to API3? Or do you mean a combination where an initial access token is added to the token of an API?

Comment: Did some reading on Delegation/Impersonation Patterns for OAuth2.0. I got what you meant. IS4 does not support these grants, so if I have these cases I will create some custom grant implementation.

Comment: API1 should be able to receive an initial access token that it forwards to API2 which forwards to API3. OAuth is meant to enable simple code. Token exchange, impersonation etc are for when you need more advanced behaviour.